# Authenticate a user on a GET API end point

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

### Problem

I have a Django REST API with a `GET` end point which I want to restrict the access to admin users. This can be done by specifying

```
permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
```

in the view.

Now I am trying to test this end point with Postman but I have 2 problems:

1. It does not work, I get a message that says *"Authentication credentials were not provided."*
2. My credentials are sent visibly in the url (because this is a `GET` end point)

### Questions

Why can't I get the expected answer from the end point when I use Postman? I am receiving what I want if I use `curl <my_url> -u <user>:<password>`.

How can I keep my API meaningful (i.e., not using `POST` when the goal of the end point is to *retrieve* data) while keeping critical credentials hidden?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you pass auth details in the URL? You have a *Basic Auth* section in POSTMAN, where you can put you login credentials. POSTMAN will then set the correct headers for you.

Remember to set `BasicAuthentication` as your auth class in DRF view or settings.

Comment: Yes you are right, I did not know these credentials were supposed to be sent in the header. Now what is the difference between the `BasicAuthentication` and the `SessionAuthentication`? How do I build my AJAX call in the API consumer?